# jquery in didInsertElement jshint error

Tags: ember-cli, jshint

when using jquery inside the component callback, the callback function for click
understands $ directly, and is working with $, but there is a jshint error

```
   components/xxx.js: line 13, col 17, '$' is not defined.
```

Using this.$ inside the jquery click callback gives an error at run time

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement() {
        this._super(...arguments);

        this.$()
        .on('click', function() {
            $('.class').something(); //ok but jshint error
            this.$('.class').something();//jshint ok but error at run time
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this at the top of the file

```
/* globals $ */
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to set the following configuration to  `.jshintrc` in the root of your app that prevents checking for the whole app which tells jshint that there are two global variables:

```
{
    "globals": {
        "$": false,
         "jQuery": false
    }
}
```

Note: If you like you can also use the jQuery version as same as Ember jQuery by changing

```
 $('.class').something(); //ok but jshint error
```

to

```
 Ember.$('.class').something();
```

which probably drops that error as well.

Comment: thanks! it works with Ember.$ but I cannot make it work with file .jshintrc. that file already contains a lot of things, I put the "globals" entry at the end but it looks like there is no effect